# Resultset in jena

Tags: resultset, jena

Hi all
how to traverse resultset returned by a query in jena .. I want to traverse each row returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite detailed recipes for this in the Jena ARQ documentation: [jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/app_api.html](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/app_api.html)